# Notice в служебном файле wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Скажите что это за функция? которая располагается в файле wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php

```
    public function pluck( $field, $index_key = null ) {
    $newlist = array();

    if ( ! $index_key ) {
        /*
         * This is simple. Could at some point wrap array_column()
         * if we knew we had an array of arrays.
         */
        foreach ( $this->output as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
                $newlist[ $key ] = $value->$field;
            } else {
*161*            $newlist[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];
            }
        }

        $this->output = $newlist;

        return $this->output;
    }

    /*
     * When index_key is not set for a particular item, push the value
     * to the end of the stack. This is how array_column() behaves.
     */
    foreach ( $this->output as $value ) {
        if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
            if ( isset( $value->$index_key ) ) {
                $newlist[ $value->$index_key ] = $value->$field;
            } else {
                $newlist[] = $value->$field;
            }
        } else {
            if ( isset( $value[ $index_key ] ) ) {
                $newlist[ $value[ $index_key ] ] = $value[ $field ];
            } else {
                $newlist[] = $value[ $field ];
            }
        }
    }

    $this->output = $newlist;

    return $this->output;
}
```

не могу понять почему я получаю такую ошибку на некоторый страницах сайта
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /home/..../..../..../wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 161
Версия php 7.4.3
Если добавить в эту строку проверку на нулевое значение ?? null ошибка исчезает, но это не правильно же менять файлы ядра, т.к. после обновления все слетит. Где искать причину?

Comment: pluck метод используется в двух функция wp_list_pluck, wp_filter_object_list думаю нужно поискать где они вызываются, скорее всего в одном из мест приходит неверный аргумент. здесь может помочь debug backtrace для того чтобы быстрее найти место где вызывается этот метод

Comment: нашел причину через query monitor